# Broken image when using include

Tags: php, html, include

I have a header and footer php file that's gonna be used on every php file that I created. I stored both of them on folder "include (inside my parent directory)". They both work fine as individual files. They are actually working when I include them on my index.php inside the parent directory. My problem is, when I used them on other files inside a folder (e.g. admin.php on admin folder), the image is broken, but when I change the path of the image relative to the admin.php, it is working properly however, the index.php now has a broken image. What could I do to fix this? Hope you understand my question. Thank you.
These are my codes:
header:

```
<div id = "header"> 
    <img id="headerImage" src="images/logo1.jpg" />
</div>
```

index:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
include 'include/header.php';?>
admin: <?php
include '../include/header.php';
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Give us any kind of visualization of your directories and files tree... anything to help us understand what's going on in your system, and the relevant parts of your PHP code.

Comment: Change `src="images/logo1.jpg"` to `src="/images/logo1.jpg"` because it's relative to the web root, not to the folder of the executing script

Comment: Sir, it's not working  both on my admin and index file. The directory /images/logo1.jpg/ is not existing relative to my header file

Comment: Can you try by src='../images/logo1.jpg'

Comment: @AzeezKallayi, i tried it sir, but it's the same. It just worked properly for the admin.php file, but in my index, the image is broken.

Comment: You need to use different header.php and put the image path accordingly

Comment: @AzeezKallayi when I run my header.php file independently, it properly shows the image. It is not broken.

Comment: Yea but here your are including that header.php inside another php. so the image path should be relatively correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your relative path.

If your project is inside a subfolder under webroot 
ex: host.com/projectname/ and you do:

```
<img id="headerImage" src="/images/logo1.jpg" />
```

This will point to host.com/ so you should include the subfolder with a forward slash before it: /projectname/images/logo1.jpg. A forward slash before a path will automaticly point to webroot. If your project lives under webroot just the slash would suffice.

If you do like you've done:

```
<img id="headerImage" src="images/logo1.jpg" />
```

Paths without forward slash at the beginning will point to the current directory it lives under.
This is the reason why it works in index.php and not in the admin page because images directory is in the same directory of index.php

Also here

```
<?php
    include '../include/header.php';
```

You should have the complete path /projectname/includes/header.php

This is because if you have to include somthing deeper in the folder structure you would have to do ../../../include/header.php. It will be hard to maintain.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the relative path, while in different folders.
What you could do is set the path to the image absolute like
http://www.domain.com/images/logo1.jpg 
Like that the image should be shown in either pages